# How to put a CString variable in a message box?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, mfc

In my program, I need put a CString variable in a MessageBox. I use the following code:

```
messagebox("hi" + txt);
```

But I get the following error message:

> error C2678: binary '+' : no operator found which takes a
>   left-hand operand of type 'const char [3]' (or there is no acceptable
>   conversion)

Comment: no it's not that is not work

Comment: The error message is quite clear as to what the problem is. Did you read it? What have you tried?

Comment: I need a code that put a CString Variable in message box

Comment: What is the type of `txt` ? If it is `CString` and your project is an unicode project, then you probably must write `messagebox(L"hi" + txt);`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use a CString variable to format, then pass it to `MessageBox`.
_T() is a macro for Unicode or MBCS.
you should make sure `txt` is same encode as `str`,

> CString str ;
>    str.Format(_T("Hi %s"), txt);

Answer (score 0):

Use format method of the CString. The Format method do thing like how printf, sprintf works.

Example

```
 CString str ;
 str.Format("Hi %s", txt);
```

Comment: Error 1 error C2664: 'void ATL::CStringT<BaseType,StringTraits>::Format(const wchar_t *,...)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'const char [6]' to 'const wchar_t *' e:\project\visual studio 2008\projects\test2\test2\test2dlg.cpp 174 test2

Comment: Unnecessary, you can concatenate two CString values using the binary `+` operator. You don't need Format unless you're actually doing some complex formatting. Either way, though, you will need to use wide string literals. Prefix them with an `L`.

Comment: plz put your code @CodyGray

Comment: Cody Gray says you can use binary + with CString itself. That is CString str = _T("Hi ") + txt.

@Cody Gray: When should I use L or _T?

Comment: Prefixing with `L` makes it a wide string. Using the `_T` macro determines at compile-time, based on some preprocessor definitions, whether the literal should be a wide or narrow string. Either one is fine, but `_T` is sort of pointless now since everything is Unicode. No one cross-compiles for ANSI or MBCS.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`_T` macro](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/72b2swax.aspx) to wrap the string literal into a `CString`:

```
messagebox(_T("hi") + txt);
```